# How do I make so I can attach an image with a !announce command on discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I know my title seems confusing, but simply, I want to make it so when I run an !announce command for discord.js, I want to add an image onto it, and it gets sent with the embed. here's an example.

When I run:
!announce (channel id) (message) THEN i attach an image, it gets sent to the channel with the message and image.

I've already got my code, I've made it so the !announce (Channel id) (message) already works, I need to know how to attach an image on the end, i dont mind the image being a link or an attachment.

Fyi, I have tried to find out how to do this, asking for help and using the discord.js documentation, but so far i've got nothing.

here's my code:

btw, i'm still on discord v12.2

```
const {MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'announce',
    description: "Does announcements in an embed",
    usage: "<channel id> <msg>",
    execute(message, args){
    if(!message.member.permissions.has(["MANAGE_MESSAGES"])) return message.reply("You don't have the required permissions to run this command.")

    let userArray = message.content.split(" ");
       let userArgs = userArray.slice(1);
       let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(userArgs[0]) || message.guild.members.cache.find(x => x.user.username.toLowerCase() === userArgs.slice(0).join(" ") || x.user.username === userArgs[0]) || message.member;

       let rChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(args [0])
       if(!rChannel)return message.channel.send('Please specify the channel ID. Usage is: ;announce <channelID> <message>')
       let MSG = message.content.split(`;announce ${rChannel.id} `).join("")
       if(!MSG)return message.reply('Please specify a message. Usage is: ;announce <channelID> <message>')
       const embed = new MessageEmbed()
       .setTitle('Announcement')
       .setDescription(`${MSG}`)
       .setImage(message.attachments.first())
       .setFooter(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
       .setTimestamp(Date.now()) 
       .setColor(0xA20B31)
       rChannel.send(embed);
    
       
   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to check if [`message.attachments`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments) has any attachments by using [`first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=first) and add the [`MessageAttachment`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/MessageAttachment) [`url`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/MessageAttachment?scrollTo=url) to the [`MessageEmbed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/MessageEmbed).

---

```js
message.attachments.first() ? embed.setImage(message.attachments.first().url) : "";
```

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "announce",
    description: "Does announcements in an embed",
    usage: "<channel id> <msg>",
    execute(message, args) {
        if (!message.member.permissions.has(["MANAGE_MESSAGES"])) return message.reply("You don't have the required permissions to run this command.");

        let userArray = message.content.split(" ");
        let userArgs = userArray.slice(1);
        let member =
            message.mentions.members.first() ||
            message.guild.members.cache.get(userArgs[0]) ||
            message.guild.members.cache.find((x) => x.user.username.toLowerCase() === userArgs.slice(0).join(" ") || x.user.username === userArgs[0]) ||
            message.member;

        let rChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(args[0]);
        if (!rChannel) return message.channel.send("Please specify the channel ID. Usage is: ;announce <channelID> <message>");
        let MSG = message.content.split(`;announce ${rChannel.id} `).join("");
        if (!MSG) return message.reply("Please specify a message. Usage is: ;announce <channelID> <message>");
        const embed = new MessageEmbed().setTitle("Announcement").setDescription(`${MSG}`).setImage(message.attachments.first()).setFooter(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL()).setTimestamp(Date.now()).setColor(0xa20b31);
        message.attachments.first() ? embed.setImage(message.attachments.first().url) : "";

        rChannel.send(embed);
    },
};
```

Comment: okay, I see, how do i implement it in though? firstly I tried making it as a let variable, then I just tried straight up putting it in the .setImage

when I put it in an embed, it says I was using embed before it was defined.

Comment: You need to put the piece of code I provided right after the embed was created, before sending it. Check my edit.

Comment: OHH, i see, you're making an embed in that way, okay, thank you so much.